# programmatically prevent scroll listview flutter

Tags: flutter

I have nested **ListView** in a **ListView**.
So I want to disable scroll for child ListView programmatically.
How to do it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set it programatically, use a setState() to update the physics type like this:

```
ScrollPhysics physics = AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();


return Stack(
  children: [
    ListView(
      physics: physics,
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Disable scrolling"),
      onPressed: () {
        setState((){
          if(physics is AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics){
            physics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
          } else {
            physics = AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();
          }
        });
      },
    ),
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent it by using physics: `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` for example

```
Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), <-----
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: status == false ? list.length : 5,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                        value: list[i], child: ListItem()),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this "physics" property value "NeverScrollableScrollPhysics" inside the nested listview.

example:

```
ListView.builder(
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
 itemBuilder: () {}
  ),
```